# Accessibility Hint is not read out when changing focus

Tags: swift, uiaccessibility

When I programmatically move voiceover focus to a label, the hint of the label is not read out. How can I fix that? Only the accessibility label is read out.

`UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification,  self.label)`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you share a code?

Answer (score 4):

Use `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` if you want to hear the hint of the new focused element.

The difference with your initial notification is [well detailed](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#notify-a-content-change) but it doesn't explain why there's such a different behavior.

Anyway, your **accessibility hint is now read out by VoiceOver when you change the focus programmatically**.